# When displaying MDI child, the child form is cut off at the top

Tags: c#, winforms, mdichild

I have a problem with a Winforms application written in VS2012(C#).
I am posting it here after lots of research and attempts with no luck.

I have 2 MDI child forms and one parent form which I use to switch between them.
After loading child1 the 1st time, the MDI form looks like it was pushed up and the top part of it is hidden and cannot be seen; this problem is resolved after the 2nd click.

This is the source of child1 which is the same code for child2

```
public partial class Child1 : Form
{
    public Child1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Top; 
        StationFormUtils.SetPanelHeaderDefinitions(panel1);
    }

    private void Child_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //removes the child bar
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
    }
}

public static void SetPanelHeaderDefinitions(Panel panel)
{
    panel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(BaseClass.StationTableWidth, BaseClass.StationHeaderHeight);
    panel.BackgroundImage = global::TestMdi.Properties.Resources.StationHeaderStrip;
    panel.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.Tile;
}
```

And this is the **source code** for the parent:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Child1 ChildMainFrm1 = new Child1();
    private Child2 ChildMainFrm2 = new Child2();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildMainFrm1.MdiParent = this;
        ChildMainFrm1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        ChildMainFrm1.Show();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChildMainFrm2.MdiParent = this;
        ChildMainFrm2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        ChildMainFrm2.Show();
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: MDI child forms don't react well to you trying to hide the MaximizeBox button.  Make sure the border style is still sizable, too.

Comment: Commenting out the line: this.MaximizeBox = false; 
didn't change a thing but defining the formborderstyle=sizable did resolve the problem!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled across this post after lots of searching and trying various things that people have recommended, as I was having a similar problem in VS2022. Like LarsTech mentioned in the comments, set the child form's `FormBorderStyle = Sizable`, either programmatically or in the form's properties.

It is worth noting that if you want to hide the control box and top bar of all child forms (the thing that holds the maximize/minimize/close buttons along with the form's name and icon in the top left), dock a `MenuStrip` control to the top of the MDi Parent of your application. Then, set `menuStrip1.Visible = false` in your MDi Parent's code behind where your `InitializeComponent()` function is. Be sure to change `menuStrip1` with the actual name of your `MenuStrip` control, if you change it. The control box and top bar of any child form will now be gone.

Some posts will say that you need to set the child form's `WindowState = Maximized`, but this is only partially true. If you only have one child form, then you need this. But, if you have multiple child forms that appear one after the other (for example, my application closes and opens different child forms based on different button presses), then you only need to have one child form with this property set (the child form that first appears in your application).

I hope this helps anyone that comes across this post, just as it helped me!